# Insert new line before each operator

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

Suppose I have a line like this:

```
abc + def - vfg *
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
abc

def

vfg
```

If only a single operator is there, I can replace: `\r\n+` with `+` but how to do it irrespective of all operators?

Is this possible using regex in Notepad++?

Comment: What did you try so far? What does your *own* research suggest?

Comment: If only a single operator is there, I can replace easily like: \r\n+ for "+" but how to do it irrespective of all operators?

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the operators doesn't matter, you can use this regex to match any of those 3 operators:

```
[\+\-\*]
```

and replace it with:

```
\r\n
```

If the order is important, you can use capture groups, and match with this regex:

```
(.*)\+(.*)\-(.*)\*
```

and replace it with:

```
$1\n$2\n$3
```